# Netgen with EIDORS

Tags: matlab, eidors

i want to run netgen in a command line in EIDORS Matlab but every time i come across this problem that matlab ask me for the path of the netgen. i receive this message every time.

'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file. 
Netgen call failed. Is netgen installed and on the search path?
If you are running under windows, I can attempt to create
a batch file to access netgen.
Please enter the directory in which to find netgen.
If you don't have a copy, download it fromhttp://www.hpfem.jku.at/netgen/

Note that you *MUST* use names without spaces. Thus
instead of C:/Program Files/ write C:/Progra~1/

netgen_path?

yet i define new system variable in windows advanced system configuration and over there i gave the path of the tcl library but it didn't work.

May any body help me ?

Answer (score 2):

Install netgen first. Go here to download:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/netgen-mesher/

Go "Files" entry to download more variant version of netgen. Take note that EIDORS 3.6 is only compatible up to the latest version of netgen-5.0.

I am using Windows 7, 64-bit Operating System. Installation of netgen with x64 and Win32 are worked fine for me. But because as you said, EIDORS requires netgen path to be no space, so when installation, I choose a path other than default "Program Files" (or similar), which has no space.

When EIDORS asks for the netgen path, give the path name until "\bin". These procedures are worked in my computer.

Answer (score 0):

You can place the `netgen.exe` path " `...\bin` " within the matlab toolbox:

[How to Set Path in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29193897/how-to-set-path-in-matlab)

thereby not needing to paste the path into EIDORS each time you run it in MATLAB.

Also downloading [EIDORS 3.8 with Netgen 5.3](http://www.sce.carleton.ca/faculty/adler/eidors/index.shtml) as a zip file avoids having to install netgen separately.