# How to save a custom colormap and use it again in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, colormap

I have created a colormap that resembles the human connectome project colormap ROY-BIG-BL, doing it manually on the colormap editor [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmuNN.png).

However, I am not able to save this as a colormap.
I tried different commands such as

```
mycmap = get(gcf,'colormap')
```

I read that with Matlab 2015 one should use gca, but this gives an error.

> Error using matlab.graphics.axis.Axes/get
>   There is no colormap property on the Axes class.

When I then try to use the saved mycmap for another figure, it ignores all modifications und uses the basic colormap parula.

Thanks for help. How can I save it and use it as another colormap in any figure I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of colormaps is deeply hidden inside the figure class, which is not accessible. So you can't save your colormap "with a name" in Matlab and access it like a normal colormap. But a colormap is nothin else than a **Yx3** matrix, you can store on disk.

```
%// custom colormap
n = 50;               %// number of colors
R = linspace(1,0,n);  %// Red from 1 to 0
B = linspace(0,1,n);  %// Blue from 0 to 1
G = zeros(size(R));   %// Green all zero
myCustomColormap = [R(:), G(:), B(:)];

%// save colormap on disk
save('myCustomColormap','myCustomColormap');

%// clear for explanation purposes
clear 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%// load colormap saved on disk
load myCustomColormap

%// assign colormap
colormap( myCustomColormap );
```

---

You used the colormap editor to create your colormap. After you applied it, use the following code to get the required matrix for further reference:

```
myCustomColormap = colormap(gca)
save('myCustomColormap','myCustomColormap');
```

If you want to make the colormap generally available to all your functions, no matter where, [**add it to your Matlab search path**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29193897/how-to-set-path-in-matlab/29193989#29193989).

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly. I integrated the obtained matrix in a m-file like in those https://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/51986-perceptually-uniform-colormaps from Anders Biguri. The colormap is now universally usable.